# How to verify text node in shadow root with robot framework keyword

Tags: selenium, robotframework, selenium-ide

I want to verify verify text node in shadow root with robot framework keyword so this is html tag

```
 <div class="styles__RadiusUnitLabel-sc-1jm4361-1 enqpSw">20 Meters</div>`
```

I try keyword with this

```
Wait until element is visible   dom:document.getElementById("react-root").shadowRoot.querySelector('div[class*="styles__RadiusUnitLabel"]').innerText
```

and get this error from robot framwork

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'

How should I verify text node for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `innerText` of the element which is a string, not a webelement. If you get rid of `innerText` at the end of your line of code that should fix this error and hopefully return the webelement you are after.

Comment: if cut of inner robot will see only element but not see text node that i want(20 Meters)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with robot, but could you define a variable like `element = dom:document.getElementById("react-root").shadowRoot.querySelector('div[class*="styles__RadiusUnitLabel"]')`, and then get the text via `element.innerText`?